# Open all excel files in a folder, perform operations and save them in the same folder with a slightly changed name looped

Tags: excel, vba, save-as

This code opens a window, where you manually choose a folder to open. After that the code opens all files in that folder one after another and saves them as a new file with a slightly changed name. What I'm trying to do is to teach it to recognize which file is open at this moment and change performed operations depending on the file name.

For example, 3 files are stored in a chosen folder: "abc_2021", "abc_total" and "aby"

How I'm trying to solve my problem:

1. store the filename value in a string
2. If the first 5 symbols of the value are "abc_2" run an additional macro (that would for example copy paste a table etc) and then save it as a new file  in the same folder using the following line

`ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs (myPath & myFile & Format(Now(),"DD-MMM-YYYY hh mm").xlsx")`

If the first 5 symbols of the value are "abc_t" run another macro here and then

`ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs (myPath & myFile & Format(Now(),"DD-MMM-YYYY hh mm").xlsx")`

Else run the 3rd macro and also save it with the proper name attached next to it

Since this operation is performed in a loop, I will have all 3 files saved in a correct format with proper operations performed on each of them.

```
Dim myPath As String
Dim myFile As String
Dim myExtension As String
Dim FldrPicker As FileDialog
Dim flName As String, Searchtext As String
Dim abc_2021 As String
Dim abc_total As String
Dim aby As String
Dim Searchstring as String

'Optimize Macro Speed
 Application.ScreenUpdating = False
 Application.EnableEvents = False
 Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

'Retrieve Target Folder Path From User
 Set FldrPicker = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)

   With FldrPicker
     .Title = "Select A Target Folder"
     .AllowMultiSelect = False
       If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode
       myPath = .SelectedItems(1) & "\"
   End With

'In Case of Cancel
NextCode:
 myPath = myPath
 If myPath = "" Then GoTo ResetSettings

'Target File Extension (must include wildcard "*")
 myExtension = "*.xls*"

'Target Path with Ending Extention
 myFile = Dir(myPath & myExtension)

'Loop through each Excel file in folder
 Do While myFile <> ""
   'Set variable equal to opened workbook
     Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=myPath & myFile)
   
   'Pause Opened Workbook to do operaions before moving on to next line of code
     DoEvents
```

And right here after the last line I need to check the name of the currently opened workbook and change performed operations depending on the file name. However, I make a mistake somewhere, because when I store them as values the debug error pops up. I tried different ways to fix it, but they don't seem to work.

Could you please help me find a solution?

This is the part of the code that gives me an error:

```
abc_2021 = "ABC_202104_vs1.xls" Searchtext = "ABC_2021" If abc_2021 Like "*#" & Searchtext & "#*.xls" Then MsgBox "I found it!"
```

In case anyone needs the last part of the code I attach it below:

```
  wb.Close SaveChanges:=True
      
    'Ensure Workbook has closed before moving on to next line of code
      DoEvents

    'Get next file name
      myFile = Dir
  Loop

'Message Box when tasks are completed
  MsgBox "Task Complete!"

ResetSettings:
  'Reset Macro Optimization Settings
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True


End Sub
```

Comment: It would help to show what you tried, and the exact error you got, and on which line.

Comment: I see (at leat) two problems here 1) `ABC_202104_vs1.xls` is not like `*#ABC_2021#*.xls`  and 2) if you saveas the files into the same directory then `myFile = Dir` will find them and you'll have an endless loop

Comment: Yes I will save files to a new directory, thank you! . Besides, I was told that the biggest problem is not making an array of all files, which can simplify the work. The code will first make an array of all files in the folder and then perform operations depending on the files name and lastly saving it all to a new directory.